# Convert factory to service in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-services

I'm using `$resource` to fetch a json from server which is working fine:

```
topicServices.factory('Topic', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/topic_api_response.json', {}, {
      fetchData: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

However, now I want to convert this factory to a service by doing something like this:

```
topicServices.service('Topic', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        this.fetchData = function() {
            var resp = $resource('http://localhost/topic_api_response.json');
            return resp;
    };
}]);
```

In doing so, I'm not able to figure out where to specify the request method (`GET/POST`) and where to give `GET/POST` params

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There's really very little difference between the *factory* and *service* providers. In regards to your query, set default params as the 2nd arg to `$resource` and customised actions as the 3rd

Comment: @Phil, "very little"? There is *no* difference once the service instance is created

Comment: @NewDev yeah, I was more referring to the way they're defined.

Comment: @Phil, in that case, there is quite a bit of difference :) hence the question... I'm just being a smartass :p

Comment: @Phil: Lets just say I feel comfortable with a service style. Also can you please elaborate your answer in the comment ?

Comment: I really don't understand. What does comfort have to do with it? `$resource` provides a great interface for dealing with RESTful APIs. If you just want one GET method that returns an array, use `$http` but why insist on using `service` instead of `factory` if the latter already works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the "service" style of defining, you should read the Angular Docs.

Anyways here is how you go: You have Separated out fetchData as a method, which seems to hit a http GET. Hence you can write your code as follows.

```
topicServices.service('Topic', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        this.fetchData = function() {
            var resp = $http.get('http://localhost/topic_api_response.json');
            return resp;
    };
}]);
```

If you want to use $resource then wrap it like below:

```
topicServices.service('Topic', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            this.myResource = function() {
                var resp = $resource('http://localhost/topic_api_response.json',params,{fetchData:{}});
                return resp;
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I wanted to see how to get this working with $resource instead of $http

Comment: in that case you would have to add a wrapper to the $resource in service like this.myResource = $resource(url,params,actions);